# Books on loans (car, house, etc...), pricing and securitization?

Tags: fixed-income, credit-risk, credit

I'm looking for a good book on credit analysis, lending, car loans, house loans, etc... I would like to understand the theory and practice behind it.  Most books I google for are for the consumer like ("how to lower your credit") and I am hoping for a good resource made for someone that gives out loans.

Thanks!

Comment: This is a very large topic and lending practices vary considerably based on the type of loan: mortgage, auto loan, student loan, p2p loan etc. If you're looking for a broad-ish introduction try: https://www.sup.org/books/title/?id=23487. Otherwise, you're better off diving into the individual sectors.

Comment: Thanks!  I will start with this just to get general ideas!